# Entity framework core, code first migration with data migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use EF Core code first migrations to de-normalise an existing table.

I have en existing table `LoginEvent` which data looks like this:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                   LoginEvent                    ║
╠════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════╣
║ Id ║ VenueRef ║ VenueName ║ OccurredAt ║ UserId ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ ven01    ║ Venue 1   ║ 2018-01-29 ║ 5      ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 2  ║ ven02    ║ Venue 2   ║ 2018-01-30 ║ 7      ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 3  ║ ven01    ║ Venue 1   ║ 2018-02-01 ║ 9      ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

```cs
public class LoginEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string VenueRef { get; set; }
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
    public DateTime OccurredAt { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to normalise this into two tables: `LoginEvent` and `Venue`, like so:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║             LoginEvent              ║
╠════╦══════════╦════════════╦════════╣
║ Id ║ VenueRef ║ OccurredAt ║ UserId ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ ven01    ║ 2018-01-29 ║ 5      ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 2  ║ ven02    ║ 2018-01-30 ║ 7      ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ 3  ║ ven01    ║ 2018-02-01 ║ 9      ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║        Venue         ║
╠══════════╦═══════════╣
║ VenueRef ║ VenueName ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣
║ ven01    ║ Venue 1   ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣
║ ven02    ║ Venue 2   ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now, I have done this by adding a new `Venue` domain object and having the `LoginEvent` reference it, like so:

```cs
public class LoginEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string VenueRef { get; set; }
    public DateTime OccurredAt { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Venue
{
    [Key]
    public string VenueRef { get; set; }
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
}
```

I've then created a migration, which (correctly):

1. Creates the new `Venue` table
2. Drops the `VenueName` column
3. Sets up the foreign key constraint between the two

However, what I need to be able to do is run a data migration between steps 1 and 2 so that the existing Venues are in the new table before dropping the column and before setting up the constraint (otherwise, I'll lose data and the constraint fails as I don't have associated Venues).

I'd like to run something like this as my data migration:

```sql
INSERT INTO Venue SELECT DISTINCT VenueRef, VenueName FROM LoginEvent
```

How should I do this?

Comment: run Add-Migration SplitEventVenueTable, then edit the Up() method in the generated migration to execute the sql comand. Save, and then run Update-Database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can execute any SQL using `migrationBuilder.Sql(theSqlString)`.

In your case

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO Venue SELECT DISTINCT VenueRef, VenueName FROM LoginEvent");
```

Run this in the migration after creating the new table `Venue` and before dropping the old column `VenueName`.

See also [Custom Migrations Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations#using-migrationbuildersql).