# Migrating One-to-Many to Many-to-Many with the new EF Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 project (migrated from ASP.NET Core 3.1).
The project uses EF Core.

EF Core 5 has built-in support for Many-to-Many. The main reason I first migrated from 3.1 to 5.0.

Now my project has a One-to-Many relationship, which I want to convert to a Many-to-Many.

Is such a relationship migration possible?

Current code:

```
    public class File
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

    public int RecordId { get; set; }

    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
    // ...
}


public class Record
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}


  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {

    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(builder);

         builder.Entity<Record>().ToTable("Record");

         // for creating GUIDs   
         builder.Entity<Record>().Property(x => x.UniqueId).HasDefaultValueSql("newid()");
         builder.Entity<File>().Property(x => x.UniqueId).HasDefaultValueSql("newid()");
     }

  }
```

In the code above you can see that a Record has zero, one or multiple Files. A File has only one record associated.

I would like to change this so that a single File can be assigned to multiple Records (this way I reduce duplicate Files and reduce disk space, improve network traffic by increased cache hits etc...).

In the File-class do I simply remove these lines of code:

```
public int RecordId { get; set; }

public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
```

and replace it with this line below?

```
public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
```

I wouldn't want to destroy and manually change many thousand file record relationships... or breaking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. public int RecordId { get; set; } // Don’t remove

   public virtual Record Record { get; set; }`
   change to

   public virtual ICollection Records { get; set; }

2.add entity

```
public class FileRecord
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }

    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

3. public DbSet FileRecords { get; set; }
4. 

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Record)
                .WithMany(p => p.Files)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RecordId);
```

Change to

```
entity.HasMany(d => d. Records)
                .WithMany(p => p.Files)
                .UsingEntity<FileRecord>(
                j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Record)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RecordId),
            j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.File)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.FileId),
            j =>
            {
                j.HasKey(t => new { t.TeamId, t.RecordId });
            });
```

5.Add-migration

```
In created migration file add
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    //……
    migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO FileRecords (FileId, RecordId) SELECT Files.Id, Files.RecordId FROM Files");
}
```

6.Check is all right, remove `public int RecordId { get; set; }` in File class
and add-migration

Comment: Great @Rif Yarullin ! I actually did it the long way manually by exporting the data, removing the table, adding it again via migration with correction relation and inserting the data again via sql server insert statements. as I was not sure if I could so that migrationbuilder.sql. thanks for pointing this out. Really think it can be useful for others also!